# How to use release toggles with Acceptance Test Driven Development?

Tags: continuous-integration, release-management, acceptance-testing, test-automation

One of the advantages of feature / release toggles is that you can integrate and deploy code without releasing it. But how does that work with ATDD? If I write some tests that are failing, because I'm not done implementing the features, even if the new implementation code is behind a toggle, I can't very well integrate those tests, can I? Otherwise the CI pipeline will fail.

Does that mean that I should have the tests behind the same toggle as the implementation? That way, when the feature is complete I can flip the toggle which will turn on the tests along with the associated implementation code?

How do teams who use release toggles and ATDD usually do it?

Comment: Why are people down-voting this question? I literally ran into this exact issue this afternoon. I've been struggling with this myself. Our team recently started using feature toggles, and our current sprint crashed and burned because we didn't have a good way to run progression tests (or have a name for them). This should be on topic, folks.

Answer (score 2):

It is matter of taste.

Basically, yes, this is a good approach. Technically, you can use the same toggle, but you may also prefer independent toggles for tests, but having some mapping, like:

- application toggle 1A - test toggle 1B
- application toggle 2A - test toggle 2B
- application toggle 3A - test toggle 3B

Thus you can have full control on tests, independent on what toggles are set for the application. For instance, you may want to check if your tests will really fail if you activate them when corresponding functionality is disabled by the application toggle.

Besides, there can be not only new tests for new functionality. An application toggle can mean also changes in the existing functionality. Thus you can decide not to have separate tests, but to use the same test and use toggle to control some parts of this test. Again, to be able to execute your tests independently with different toggles on the fixed application state, you may want to prefer independent toggles for tests.

Answer (score 2):

Tests should be written so that they are aware of which toggles need to be on (and by default which ones should be off) and set those toggles up as part of test setup.

As for the CI, these tests aren't regression tests yet. So they don't need to run as part of the CI regression test suite. So they shouldn't "block" the build, however you probably still want to run the progression tests, so add a step to run progressions tests separately from regression tests which doesn't block if there is an error.

The build would look something like this:

```
  > Checkout
  > Build
  > Unit Test
  > Regression Test
  > In parallel
     > Progression Test
     > Package and deployment
```

You can achieve this by:

- tagging progression tests,
- or by tagging regression tests,
- or by having each set of tests categorised and telling the CI which categories are regression/progression. (simple enough to do with a text file called progression.txt)